# mergeWith for [Object]

Tags: functional-programming, lodash, ramda.js

Is there any recommended approach or function to combine the fn functionality of R.mergeWith with n list items, like R.mergeAll?

I have

```
const data = [
  { a: 1, b: 2, c: 0, d: { e: 3 }},
  { a: 1, c: -1 },
  { a: 1, b: 4, c: 0, d: { e: 2 }}
]
```

and want to sum all values by key, to return

```
{ a: 3, b: 6, c: -1, d: { e: 5 }}
```

I've tried something like

```
R.mapAccum((a, b) => R.mergeWith(R.sum, a, b), {}, data)
```

(in [REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?code=const%20data%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%7B%20a%3A%201%2C%20b%3A%202%2C%20c%3A%200%2C%20d%3A%20%7B%20e%3A%203%20%7D%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%20a%3A%201%2C%20c%3A%20-1%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%20a%3A%201%2C%20b%3A%204%2C%20c%3A%200%2C%20d%3A%20%7B%20e%3A%202%20%7D%7D%0A%5D%0A%0AR.mapAccum%28%28a%2C%20b%29%20%3D%3E%20R.mergeWith%28R.sum%2C%20a%2C%20b%29%2C%20%7B%7D%2C%20data%29)) guessing what I'm after is a way to mergeWith the previous and current object, through some fn.

Any ideas how I could do that in a terse, pure way with a functional library? I prefer Ramda, but anything would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ramda does not currently have a `mergeDeep` or `mergeDeepWith` function.  But it's likely to be added soon.  See [PR 1867](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/pull/1867).

With that in place, you could simply do

```
R.reduce(R.mergeDeepWith(R.add), {}, data)
```

You can see a simulation of what this would be like in the **[REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?code=const%20mergeDeepWithKey%20%3D%20curry%28function%20mergeDeepWithKey%28fn%2C%20lObj%2C%20rObj%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20return%20mergeWithKey%28function%28k%2C%20lVal%2C%20rVal%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20if%20%28R.is%28Object%2C%20lVal%29%20%26%26%20R.is%28Object%2C%20rVal%29%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20mergeDeepWithKey%28fn%2C%20lVal%2C%20rVal%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20fn%28k%2C%20lVal%2C%20rVal%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%7D%2C%20lObj%2C%20rObj%29%3B%0A%20%7D%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20mergeDeepWith%20%3D%20curry%28function%20mergeDeepWith%28fn%2C%20lObj%2C%20rObj%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20return%20mergeDeepWithKey%28function%28k%2C%20lVal%2C%20rVal%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20return%20fn%28lVal%2C%20rVal%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%7D%2C%20lObj%2C%20rObj%29%3B%0A%20%7D%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20mergeDeep%20%3D%20curry%28function%20mergeDeep%28lObj%2C%20rObj%29%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20mergeDeepWithKey%28function%28k%2C%20lVal%2C%20rVal%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20rVal%3B%0A%20%20%7D%2C%20lObj%2C%20rObj%29%3B%0A%7D%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20data%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%7B%20a%3A%201%2C%20b%3A%202%2C%20c%3A%200%2C%20d%3A%20%7B%20e%3A%203%20%7D%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%20a%3A%201%2C%20c%3A%20-1%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%20a%3A%201%2C%20b%3A%204%2C%20c%3A%200%2C%20d%3A%20%7B%20e%3A%202%20%7D%7D%0A%5D%3B%0A%0AR.reduce%28%28x%2C%20y%29%20%3D%3E%20mergeDeepWith%28R.add%2C%20x%2C%20y%29%2C%20%7B%7D%2C%20data%29%0A%0AR.reduce%28mergeDeepWith%28R.add%29%2C%20%7B%7D%2C%20data%29%0A)**.

(You need to use `add` rather than `sum` because `reduce` means working with one pair of objects at a time.  `add` is for two numbers, `sum` is for a list of them.)

Comment: That's great! Thanks a lot for sharing the implementation. I'll learn a lot from that.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have no cyclic structures in your object, this will solve your problem.

```
function merge(array){
  // Returns merged array
  return mergeSubArray(array);

  // This function recursively process all sub-arrays
  function mergeSubArray(subArray){

    // Sum all properties of all objects in the array
    return subArray.reduce(function(previousObject, currentObject){

      // Get all properties of an object
      Object.keys(currentObject).forEach(function(keyOfCurrentObject){
        /*
          For all properties we need to check whether this type if number or object.
          If we encountered a number, we simply add it to previous sum.
          Otherwise, if it is an object, call this function to it.
        */

        if(typeof previousObject[keyOfCurrentObject] == 'number'){
          previousObject[keyOfCurrentObject] += currentObject[keyOfCurrentObject];
        }else{
          previousObject[keyOfCurrentObject] = mergeSubArray([previousObject[keyOfCurrentObject], currentObject[keyOfCurrentObject]]);
        }
      });

      // Returns merged objects
      return previousObject;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you a) added an explanation and b) warned about the recursion which is not super-obvious because c) you unfortunately use single letter variable names and even shadow some of them in inner functions.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for rolling back your edit. I've made it clearer now that it's being asked in the context of FP libraries. Ramda in particular. Upvoting here for now.

Comment: @JaredSmith I thought that it is obvious how my code works, but its ok, I updated my answer.

Comment: @jiku Why using Ramda when it is easier to do it in pure Javascript? Also, I think this is the shortest solution because there is no Ramda library to do exactly what you want.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer171 mostly just to learn and work with FP and Ramda. I'm hoping it can be done in a couple of lines, without becoming unclear.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer171 's answer is about as short as its going to get. And as for my points, while the code may have been perfectly clear to you remember you a writing it to educate the OP. I would also arguing that shadowing a variable in a one-off lambda passed to reduce is inherently unclear, but YMMV. +1.